# installing updates on multiple ubuntu machines

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to find out if there is a way to connect with multiple ubuntu machines and install updates simultaneously.

Ideally, if I enter a command "sudo apt-get update" from one machine, it should execute in all the ubuntu machines that I am connected to.

I looked at TMUX but not sure if that would be appropriate. Also found apt-cacher but connecting with other systems using their IP remains unclear.

any help and reference will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, tmux is capable of connecting to multiple machines and running commands simultaneously. Connect to each host in a pane and use the 'synchronize-panes' window option to send each pane the same keyboard input simultaneously.

The command looks like:

```
:setw synchronize-panes
```

Following is a complete example, let's create a window with 3 panes, each logged into a different server:

```
$ tmux new -s 'update packages' 'ssh admin@host1' \; split-window -h 'ssh admin@host2' \; split-window -h 'ssh admin@host3' \; select-layout even-horizontal
```

Once you have logged into the servers being upgraded, on the tmux prompt (C-b :), enter 'setw synchronize-panes'

[image: Synchronize-panes option]

Now everything you type will be input to all panes

[image: Synced Panes]

Note: As mentioned in another post, tools like 'pssh' and 'csshX' may be better suited for this purpose.

Comment: fantastic! I am going to try this one out today

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with parallel-ssh provided in pssh you can just do that. It executes a command in parallel on all of the machines you want.
Here is the man page : http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/parallel-ssh.1.html

Install it with apt-get install pssh

Or

apt-get install parallel-ssh